# Sending only a chunk of data (over CoreBlueTooth)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, core-bluetooth

I am working on an iOS app which needs to transfer audio data between to devices using CoreBlueTooth. This is the issue I am currently facing.

First, the related Swift code:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(name)", ofType: nil)!,
url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

do {let audioData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    // do something useful with audioData to send it
    // to the other device.
    ..........
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Up to this point it is working, the next step is where a problem comes up.

I get some return (by the CoreBlueTooth process flow) letting me know that n bytes have been received (by the other device). Therefore, I need to repeat what I did above, taking the data from the same file, but letting alone the first n bytes. In other words starting at byte n+1. Something like:

```
do {let audioData = try GetBytes(n+1...lastByte, of:Data(contentsOf: url))
.......
```

What is the proper way (Syntax) to do that and get the result I need?

I have already done some research on how to manipulate only a range of the contents of Data. But did not find anything simple and clear.

Comment: To transfer a large amount of data such as an audio file you would be better off using an L2CAP stream. Chunking the file into 20 byte packets and reassembling these at he other end will be slow. https://github.com/paulw11/L2CapDemo

Comment: I am using L2CAP. This question is related to a problem I have while doing that. The value of n in my post is not 20 bytes at all, it is more like a few thousand bytes.

Comment: If your can fit the whole file in memory, just read it once and then use [subscripting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1779919-subscript) to access the next bit you need, but it might be simpler to open an input stream for your source file rather than reading it into a `Data` instance. Then you can simply read from the input stream and write to the output stream.

Comment: (Yes I can fit the whole file) Well the ""subscripting" you mention seems to be what I am trying to do with Data, but I don't know how to do it properly (this is the issue). Concerning "read from the input stream and write to the output stream", this is also what I intended to do, but don't quit know how to do it correclty. My knowledge of L2CAP Channel is limited, apart from a demo I put on GitHub a while ago (https://github.com/zaxonus/L2CAP-Channel-Get-Started). it doesn't go much further.

Comment: @Paulw11. I just made a post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57751590/trying-to-understand-l2cap-channel) which is basically a question about your demo.